# String representation in Java

Tags: java

A String is represented as objects in Java. Accordingly, an object contains values stored in *instance variables* within the object. An object also contains bodies of code that operate upon the object. These bodies of code are called **methods**.

---

Objects that contain the same types of values and the same methods are grouped together into classes. A class may be viewed as a type definition for those objects. Accordingly, how is a String in Java represented? Let's consider the following code snippet in Java.

```
 final public class Main
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String s="black lion";
        String s1=new String(s);

        System.out.println(s.toUpperCase());
        System.out.println("black lion".toUpperCase());
        System.out.println(s1.toUpperCase());
    }
}
```

---

The above code displays the String after converting it into uppercase. In this statement `String s="black lion";` , Where is the String being assigned. Is it being assigned into an instance variable within the String class or somewhere? and in this statement `"black lion".toUpperCase();`. Is it an object of the String class? How?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A string is a `char[]` containing a series of [UTF-16 code units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), an `int` offset into that array, and an `int` length.

I think the source of your confusion is the idea that

```
String s
```

creates a string that is assigned into.

It does not.  It creates space for a string reference.  Assigning copies references around but does not modify the objects to which those references refer.

You should also be aware that

```
new String(s)
```

doesn't really do anything useful.  It merely creates another instance backed by the same array, offset, and length as `s`.  There is very rarely a reason to do this so it is considered bad practice by most Java programmers.

Java double quoted strings like `"my string"` are really references to [interned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning) `String` instances so `"foo"` is a reference to the same String instance regardless of how many times it appears in your code.

Comment: so `String hello = new String("hello");` will create two "hello" string object in string pool or one?

Comment: The `"hello"` creates one instance that is pooled, and the `new String(...)` creates a non-pooled instance.  Try `System.out.println(("hello" == "hello") + "," + (new String("hello") == "hello") + "," + (new String("hello") == new String("hello")));` and you should see `true,false,false`.

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in Java, so when you do a `println`, a new `String` is created by the `toUpperCase` (and later garbage collected).

Answer (score 1):

If I get what you want to know. The String object is represented by the double quotes `"`. This is called the String literal.