# String representation in Java and compacting Strings

Tags: java, string

Recently I stumbled upon this [JEP 254: Compact Strings](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) which basically targets:

> Summary: Adopt a more space-efficient internal representation for strings.

From my current experience, `Strings` and `char[]` occupies huge percentage of total heap consumption. Like the JIRA already states:

> The current implementation of the String class stores characters in a char array, using two bytes (sixteen bits) for each character. Data gathered from many different applications indicates that strings are a major component of heap usage and, moreover, that most String objects contain only Latin-1 characters. Such characters require only one byte of storage, hence half of the space in the internal char arrays of such String objects is going unused.

Considering this, I have below questions:

- How is this issue handled currently by other developers when `String` is storing only chars requiring 1 byte and also constitute a large part of heap profile?
- Why this is being implemented now and have not been attempted a solution for this earlier?
- Are there already open source libraries which target solving this issue?

I have gone through basic questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069848/string-representation-in-java) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34474284/java-how-exactly-string-intern-and-stringpool-works) regarding facts about `String` which covers How `StringPool` and interning `String` works and Why single char in String currently occupies `2 bytes`.

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean "only UTF-8 chars"?

Comment: I mean only such characters which will need only a byte to store.

Comment: I see. Always cool to invent your own terms. You may be referring to ASCII (essentially 0-127 range of Unicode) or Latin-1 as your post mentions in other part - consider if coming up with your own term is necessary.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually attempted earlier: in Java-6 there was an option `-XX:+UseCompressedStrings` which enabled the feature similar to JEP 254. However this feature was dropped in Java-7 due to additional complexity (which introduced bugs like [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7190247) or [this](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7192322)) and performance losses. One of the problems was that these times strings were capable to share the underlying buffer (`substring()` returned a new string which shared the same buffer with the original string). This added much complexity to string compactization (what if original string uses non-Latin1 symbols while substring uses Latin-1 only?).

Now string buffers are never shared between non-equal strings, so the implementation became easier. Nevertheless it's quite hard and involves many caveats. One of JEP 254 goals is to try very hard in order not to lose even a tiny bit of performace. Dont' forget that `String` class is very basic: some of its methods (like `equals`, `indexOf`) are intrinsified by JIT-compiler; some scenarios are handled specially (like optimization of String concatenation). All of these features heavily rely on the internal String representation and should be rewritten as well for compact strings.

If you want to compactify your current code, you may implement custom `CompactString` which implements `CharSequence` interface and uses `byte[]` internally. The problem is that tons of existing code works with `String`, not with `CharSequence` and `CharSequence` interface is actually very limited. So it would be quite hard to use such class widely.

Answer (score 1):

UTF-8 is a character encoding that works for all Unicode characters, Java strings store in UTF-16 encoding instead, and they do that always. Implementing a variable striong storage would likely be a huge performance hit, as the JVM would have to decide first whether it's looking at a Latin-1 string value or a UTF-16 one.

Also, UTF16 encoding provides more consistent handling of string properties and operations. Latin-1 strings would have to be converted to UTF-16 first to append non-Latin-1 characters. Also, comparing a Latin-1 string to a UTF-16 string is quite a messy thing. Essentially you would have to convert the Latin-1 string to a UTF-16 string (or at least iterate over it via the `CharSequence` interface) for almost all operations.

Answer (score -1):

The in-memory representation/encoding of `char` (and therefore `String`) in Java is `UTF-16` requiring (at least) 2 bytes per **any** character. Even if you're using characters and encodings in your program that would require a single byte in other charsets (`Latin-1`, part of `UTF-8`, etc.).

This issue might not have been most relevant earlier, but now with multi gigabyte heaps and who knows what other reasons they're taking a new look on slimming down the JVM heap signature.

Since this is a JVM internal issue, there are no libraries that *could* affect it. You would need a custom JVM which could be non-conforming to the rules (assuming the UTF-16 encoding is specified somewhere).

Comment: I am already aware about that fact and mentioned the same in the question too. Last two are not questions but are stuff I already am aware of.

Comment: Then what is your `How is this handled currently` question supposed to mean?

Comment: I mean how other developer get past this issue? Edited just to be clear if anyone else is confused

Comment: There's nothing to get past. If you don't have enough memory for your Strings, then buy more memory.

Comment: Can't the byte array be used to tackle this in a way? but then we always end up converting it to strings, so not sure.

Comment: It's so nice of you to consider everyone else as dumb people and yourself as the smarter one.

Comment: I don't consider everyone else dumb. You're just not being very clear in your questions or comments. The first comment to your question was "what do you mean 'only UTF-8 chars'", and your comments to my answer haven't been very understandable either.